# Focus on textbox when radiobutton is selected in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, textbox, radio-button, focus

can someone please give me an idea on how will i set focus on my textbox when I click the radiobutton assigned to it? Im using angular js. Thanks for any idea

Comment: What is the DOM structure..?

Comment: @TJ i does not have DOM structure as of the moment :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rpKlwheIJ4GFf07Fnpc2?p=preview) for you.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="scopeExample">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat='item in mas'>
      <input type="radio" name='somename' ng-model="item.select" value="true" ng-click='clear(item)'>
      <input type='text' focus='item.select'/>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.mas=[
      {id:1,select:false},
      {id:2,select:false},
      {id:3,select:false},
      {id:4,select:false}
      ];

  $scope.clear = function(item){
    $scope.mas.forEach(function(x){
      if(x != item)
        x.select=false;
    });
  }

  }]).directive('focus',['$timeout', '$parse', function($timeout, $parse){

    return {
      link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs['focus']);
            scope.$watch(model, function (value) {                
                if (eval(value)) 
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element[0].focus();
                    });                
            });
    }
  }

  }]);
```

Comment: i am upvoting your answer over mine. Since, you went in detail. Good Job.

Comment: Thanks, our answers are very similar, indeed. Also check how your code works at case of using inside ng-repeat directive when only one radio can be selected. I suppose that is what @bleykFaust need.

Comment: Thanks @SlavaUtesinov

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you pseudo code which you can alter on the basis of your needs. For now, the code has one radio button which when selected will focus on the input element. However, you can achieve those on list, on checkbox as per your need.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="focusRadio" value=0>
    <input ng-model="name" focus>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('focus', function() {
    return function(scope, element) {
       scope.$watch('focusRadio', 
         function (newValue) { 
            newValue && element[0].focus()
         })
    }      
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {}
```

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ABHCRIm95EyNUI8nWczh?p=preview . Change the input type to checkbox to better know about the functionality.